# Can my mother keep the money in my custodial account from me?

Tags: united-states, savings-account, minor

I'm seventeen, about to be eighteen in five months, and the other day, my mother said that if I didn't prove that I can be responsible with my money, she would stop me from closing my custodial account. Can she do that? We live in New York.

Comment: Depends on the exact terms of the custodial arrangement. You'd need to find a lawyer, have them look at it (do you have or can you get a copy?), and possibly take it to court... which, unless you can find a pro-bono lawyer, might cost you a sizable chunk of change and not get you the money any faster than "being responsible" for five months. Pick your battles.

Comment: only a lawyer can answer the question... and it's probably the wrong question.

Comment: Listen to your mom!

Answer (score 4):

See the article [Age of Majority and Trust Termination](http://www.finaid.org/savings/ageofmajority.phtml). The site happens to be college related, but the chart offering age at which the minor takes control of the custodial account, by state should help address your question. For NY, it's 21, not 18. Same in my state. For custodial accounts we have for our daughter, she can show ID and take over at 21 if she wishes. Both smart enough to know she can, and wise enough to put the transfer off.